# Check whether a session is new in PHP

Tags: php, http, session, session-cookies, sessionid

I have a website that needs to perform a certain backend function once per user session. I therefore want to be able to determine whether any given page view is the first within a given session.

According to the PHP docs:

> **session_start()** creates a session or resumes the current one based on
>   a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a
>   cookie.

So is there any way to know whether the session is being created or resumed?

Or is this a situation where I have to check the current session ID against a list I maintain on the server, to check if it's been registered before? If so, does this necessitate writing to a database, or is there a less cumbersome, in-memory way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['exists'])){
    //handle completely new session here
}
$_SESSION['exists'] = true;
.... //continue on with normal request
```

Comment: You should use `!isset()` instead of `empty()`. If the key does not exist, PHP is going to throw a Notice error with `empty()`.

Comment: Animuson - PHP doesn't throw notices for empties when the key doesn't exist in 5.3. Probably true of earlier versions as well.

Answer (score 5):

All documented ways of checking for session "newness" have failed me in the past, so I tend to do

```
$_SESSION['existing']=true;
```

when starting a session, and then just testing

```
if (isset($_SESSION['existing'])) ...
```

Comment: Thanks- confirms what Kenaniah said

Answer (score 3):

Check if `$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']` is defined (or whatever the cookie name is if you changed it from default.

If the cookie doesn't exist, then the session has just been created.

Comment: Which won't work if the session is propagated via another mechanism than cookies.